# Identify certain process among various duplicate processes in windows and close it

Tags: windows, command-line, process

I am running 2 eclipse processes from different folders in Windows OS and I want to close one of them using command line. If I say - taskkill /IM eclipse.exe, it closes both the process. How can I identify that which process is running from which directory and based on that close the certain process using command line ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a powershell scipt :

example to find putty process :

```
PS>get-process put* |select name, path                                                                                                                   

  Name  Path                                           
----  ----                                           
putty C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\PuTTY\putty.exe  
putty C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\PuTTY\putty.exe  
putty C:\temp\putty.exe
```

Stop the process started from temp folder :

```
get-process putty | ? { $_.path -match "c:\\temp"} |stop-process -force
```